# Aligning edges in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I've made a diagram in tikz, see below, and after some messing around I've been able to align all nodes properly. I say 'messing around' because I find the documentation impossible to navigate, so I've resorted to randomly trying out commands and syntax for this. A problem I'm unable to resolve though, is how to align the *edges* in the diagram:

[image]

I would like the edges on the right to connect `$\overline{1}$` to `$\overline{H}$`, and `$\overline{H}$` to `$\overline{G}$`, with the expressions `$=H/N$` and `$=G/N$` sticking out to the side. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (1.0,4.5)  []      (A1) {$G$};
\node at (2.5,4.5)  [right] (B1) {$\overline{G}=G/N$};
\node at (1.0,3.0)  []      (A2) {$H$};
\node at (2.5,3.0)  [right] (B2) {$\overline{H}=H/N$};
\node at (1.0,1.5)  []      (A3) {$N$};
\node at (2.5,1.5)  [right] (B3) {$\overline{1}$};
\node at (1.0,0.0)  []      (A4) {$1$};

\path[-stealth] (A1) edge node[above] {$\pi$} (B1)
                     edge[-] (A2)
                (A2) edge node[above] {} (B2)
                     edge[-] (A3)
                (A3) edge node[above] {} (B3)
                     edge[-] (A4)
                (B1) edge[-] (B2)
                (B2) edge[-] (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution:

Load the mathtools package `\usepackage{mathtools}` and use `\rlap` to let the right part of the equations not count to the bounding box of the node:

```
\node at (2.5,4.5)  [right] (B1) {$\overline{G}\mathrlap{{}=G/N}$};
\node at (2.5,3.0)  [right] (B2) {$\overline{H}\mathrlap{{}=H/N}$};
```

However, this has some drawbacks. `$\overline{1}$` and `\overline{H}` do not have the same width, so the edges will not be exactly vertical.
To circumvent this, you can set the text width of all nodes to the same value with `[text width=1em,align=center]`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{symbol/.style={text width=1em,align=center}}
        \node at (1.0,4.5)  [symbol]      (A1) {$G$};
        \node at (2.5,4.5)  [symbol,right] (B1) {$\overline{G}\mathrlap{{}=G/N}$};
        \node at (1.0,3.0)  [symbol]       (A2) {$H$};
        \node at (2.5,3.0)  [symbol,right] (B2) {$\overline{H}\mathrlap{{}=H/N}$};
        \node at (1.0,1.5)  [symbol]       (A3) {$N$};
        \node at (2.5,1.5)  [symbol,right] (B3) {$\overline{1}$};
        \node at (1.0,0.0)  [symbol]       (A4) {$1$};

        \path[-stealth] (A1) edge node[above] {$\pi$} (B1)
            edge[-] (A2)
            (A2) edge node[above] {} (B2)
            edge[-] (A3)
            (A3) edge node[above] {} (B3)
            edge[-] (A4)
            (B1) edge[-] (B2)
            (B2) edge[-] (B3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I always use a `matrix of math nodes` for diagrams like this (some people prefer the [tikzcd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package). This allows you to place the objects in your diagram in a matrix/array and then add arrows at will.

For your diagram I wrote type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[looseness=.5,auto]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
        G & \overline{G}=G/N\\
        H & \overline{H}=H/N\\
        N & \overline{1}\\
        1\\
     };
     \draw[->] (M-1-1)--node{$\pi$}(M-1-2);
     \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xx using int(\x+1)] in {1,2} {
        \draw(M-\x-1)--(M-\xx-1);
        \draw(M-\x-2)--(M-\xx-2);
     }
    \draw[->](M-2-1)--(M-2-2);
    \draw[->](M-3-1)--(M-3-2);
    \draw[->](M-3-1)--(M-4-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

If you are already familiar with [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) then this is mostly self-explanatory. The most interesting point is that the `(M)` after the `\matrix` tells `tikz` that the nodes in the matrix can be referred to using `M-<row>-<col>`. You can change `(M)` to anything you like.

**EDIT**

I personally, like the alignment in the diagram above but I accept that this is not to everyone's tastes. By adding a little bit of styling it is possible to move the lines on the right-hand side of the diagram. Styling of nodes inside a matrix can be achieved by putting it inside `|[<style>]|` -- that is, by giving an optional argument `[<style>]` to the implicit node command that it used for the matrix entries (and then enclosed in `|...|`). Using styling we can make the node left aligned and wide enough. After this we can tweak the vertical lines on the right-hand side to produce:

[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[looseness=.5,auto,
        leftnodes/.style={text width=3em, align=left}]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
        G & |[leftnodes]|\overline{G}=G/N\\
        H & |[leftnodes]|\overline{H}=H/N\\
        N & |[leftnodes]|\overline{1}\\
        1\\
     };
     \draw[->] (M-1-1)--node{$\pi$}(M-1-2);
     \draw(M-1-1)--(M-2-1);
     \draw([xshift=2mm]M-1-2.south west)--([xshift=2mm]M-2-2.north west);
     \draw(M-2-1)--(M-3-1);
     \draw([xshift=2mm]M-2-2.south west)--([xshift=2mm]M-3-2.north west);
    \draw[->](M-2-1)--(M-2-2);
    \draw[->](M-3-1)--(M-3-2);
    \draw[->](M-3-1)--(M-4-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A *much simpler* way of doing this is simply to put the "offending" parts of the equations inside `\rlap{$...$}`, which essentially tells LaTeX to typeset them but leave the cursor alone. With this minor change, the code becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[looseness=.5,auto]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
        G & \overline{G}\rlap{$=G/N$}\\
        H & \overline{H}\rlap{$=H/N$}\\
        N & \overline{1}\\
        1\\
     };
     \draw[->] (M-1-1)--node{$\pi$}(M-1-2);
     \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xx using int(\x+1)] in {1,2} {
        \draw(M-\x-1)--(M-\xx-1);
        \draw(M-\x-2)--(M-\xx-2);
     }
    \draw[->](M-2-1)--(M-2-2);
    \draw[->](M-3-1)--(M-3-2);
    \draw[->](M-3-1)--(M-4-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the output is the same as in the second image above.

Comment: @Servaes I actually like this alignment:) But as you're not, and because it's your question, I have shown how to change this using a `matrix of nodes`.

Answer (score 4):

I feel it's a typical `tikz-cd` usage case, so, I suggest the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}    
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[r,"\pi"]\arrow[dash,d] & \overline{G}=G/N \arrow[dash,d] \\
H \arrow[r] \arrow[dash,d]      & \overline{H}=H/N \arrow[dash,d] \\
N \arrow[r] \arrow[dash,d]      & \overline{1}                    \\
1
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you still prefer the left-alignment (certainly I don't, but, it is your question) you can play with the tikzcd a little like this:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[r,"\pi"]\arrow[dash,d] & \arrow[dash,d] \mathrlap{\overline{G}=G/N} \\
H \arrow[r] \arrow[dash,d]      & \arrow[dash,d] \mathrlap{\overline{H}=H/N} \\
N \arrow[r] \arrow[dash,d]      & \mathrlap{\overline{1}}                    \\
1
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: @Servaes -- Having troubles installing the `tikzcd` is totally another issue for which you're welcome to submit a separate question. For your current question, I updated my answer to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xshift` to shift the endpoints of the connecting lines:

```
([xshift=-18pt]B1.south) edge[-] ([xshift=-19pt]B2.north)
([xshift=-19pt]B2.south) edge[-] (B3)
```

Another option could be to split the nodes into two parts (the following code is based on the `positioning` library to avoid writing exact coordinates):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm] % standard distance between nodes
\node                      (A1) {$G$};
\node [right of=A1]        (B1) {$\overline{G}$};
\node [right=0.25cm of B1] (C1) {$= G/N$}; % second part of B1
\node [below of=A1]        (A2) {$H$};
\node [below of=B1]        (B2) {$\overline{H}$};
\node [right=0.25cm]       (C2) {$= H/N$}; % second part of B2
\node [below of=A2]        (A3) {$N$};
\node [below of=B2]        (B3) {$\overline{1}$};
\node [below of=A3]        (A4) {$1$};

\path[-stealth] (A1) edge node [above] {$\pi$} (B1)
                     edge[-] (A2)
                (A2) edge (B2)
                     edge[-] (A3)
                (A3) edge (B3)
                     edge[-] (A4)
                (B1) edge[-] (B2)
                (B2) edge[-] (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```